# NvBackend.exe Destroying .exe files and unable to be ended (access denied)

Tags: troubleshooting, process

For the past couple of weeks a process called NvBackend.exe has been running on my computer and through research, it appears to be associated with Nvidia. However occasionally when I launch a program, it will tell me that the file (the .exe I'm attempting to launch) is currently in use by NvBackend.exe, and when I check that file the size has dropped to 0 kb and unable to be used. I cannot end the process at all, nor will it let me see a file location (I've checked manually and cannot find it at all). I've tried using the command prompt to end it and I had no luck with that either. I have not seen anyone have a similar problem, nor have I seen anything related to NvBackend

Comment: It is very unlikely that the,  GeForce Experience background service, which handles updates executable is destorying files.

Comment: I forgot to write in that it says the file is being used by NvBackend

Comment: You don't indicate what file though.  You can disable the background Nvidia updater if you want but I have serious doubts it will help.  Tens of millions of users have the GeForce Experience installed and don't have this problem.

Comment: The file that gets "destroyed" is the .exe of programs i've been trying to launch. I've had this problem with skype, discord, google chrome, tor, steam, and several others where the .exe is being used by NvBackend.exe (according to windows) and the .exe becomes unusable afterwards, because it has a size of zero bytes

Comment: So uninstall GeForce Experience and see if you can reproduce the problems without it being installed.  This of course means you wouldn't have display drivers, and I suggest, using the drivers you can download from Microsoft Update at that point.

Comment: It's entirely possible this is a malicious executable that is using the same name as a well-known, otherwise reputable application. Try uploading the `NvBackend.exe` to www.virustotal.com and also run a virus scan of your system.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Nvidia Streamer Service helps us to fix the [nvbackend.exe](http://techstuffsarena.com/2019/02/22/nvbackend-exe/) issue